# Show progress bar when running a script

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have developed the python script for checking out a source code from repository and build it using visual studio.When i run the script,a GUI opens(developed using wxPython) which shows a button,clicking on which does the checkout and build.I would want to show a progress bar showing the process running when i click on the button and a success message after the script finishes it's work.Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody show me a demo code of a progress bar? It would be good if i have a good looking progress bar.(animated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't be able to get an accurate progress unless your build scripts are generating some progress information in the output that you can parse and represent in your GUI.  Either way you will probably want to use wx.ProgressDialog or use a wx.Gauge in your main panel or something like that.  Both wx.ProgressDialog and wx.Gauge can be used in a mode that shows actual values (a percentage complete) or an 'indeterminate' mode that represents that something is happening but there isn't any way to tell how far in the process it is.

Comment: Ok.Thank you. I had a look on wx.Guage where it was asking for a range of the task.How would i specify a range without knowing how much time a task would take to finish? I just want show a guage which indicates a process is running and a complete message when it is done.

Comment: Call Pulse periodically instead of Update.  That puts the gauge in "indeterminate mode".